# Adding postcss and autoprefixer to webpack 2 doesn't prefix

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-2, postcss, autoprefixer

I'm trying to migrate to webpack 2, and I can't seem to get postcss-loader to autoprefix.  I read docs, but I can't seem to find the issue. Has anyone run into this problem? If so, could you assist me in resolving my issue?

```js
webpack.config.js
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

// development variables
const DEVELOPMENT = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';
const PRODUCTION = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

// checks if production : development
const entry = PRODUCTION
    ?   [
            './src/index.js'
        ]
    :   [
            './src/index.js',
            'webpack/hot/dev-server',
            'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost8080',
    ];

const plugins = PRODUCTION
    ?   [
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
            new ExtratTextPlugin('style-[contenthash:10].css'),
            new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
                template: 'index-template.html'
            })
        ]
    :   [
            new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({ options: { postcss: [ autoprefixer(), ] } }),
            new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        ];

plugins.push(
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        DEVELOPMENT: JSON.stringify(DEVELOPMENT),
        PRODUCTION: JSON.stringify(PRODUCTION),
    })
);

// add class name depending on enviroment PROD | DEV
const cssIndentifier = PRODUCTION ? '[hash:base64:10]' : '[path][name]---[local]';

// inject into head in DEV and create CSS file in PROD
const cssLoader = PRODUCTION
    ?   ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
            loader: 'css-loader?minimize&localIdentName=' + cssIndentifier
        })
    :   ['style-loader','css-loader?localIdentName=' + cssIndentifier + ',postcss-loader'];

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'source-map', //add source mapping to devtools
    entry: entry,
    plugins: plugins,
    externals: {
        jquery: 'jQuery' //jquery is external and availabe at the global variable jQuery
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader:['babel-loader'],
            exclude: /node_modules/
        }, {
            test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
            loader:['url-loader?10000&name=images/[hash.12].[ext]'],//use url loader if image is over 10k : use file loader
            exclude: /node_modules/
        }, {
            test: /\.css$/,
            loaders: cssLoader,
            exclude: /node_modules/
        }]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: PRODUCTION ? '' : '/dist/',
        filename: PRODUCTION ? 'bundle.[hash:12].min.js' : 'bundle.js'
    }
};


package.json
{
  "name": "starter",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "starter project using webpack 2",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rimraf dist && NODE_ENV=production webpack",
    "dev": "NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "repository": "https://github.com/rafh/starter-project.git",
  "author": "Rafael Heard rafael.heard@gmail.com",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^6.7.6",
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.23.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.3.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.22.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.2",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.10.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "loader": "^2.1.1",
    "postcss-loader": "^1.3.3",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.2",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple issues with your webpack config, and frankly I don't know which one would be causing the issue, so I'll outline all of them and hopefully one of them fixes the issue.

`cssLoader` defines the array improperly, from what I can tell - the arrow is accidentally included in a string with a plus sign, when it should separate the array:

```
PRODUCTION
    ?   ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
            loader: 'css-loader?importLoaders=1&minimize&localIdentName=' + cssIndentifier
        })
    :   ['style-loader','css-loader?importLoaders=1&localIdentName=' + cssIndentifier, 'postcss-loader'];
```

For webpack 2, the proper syntax for using loaders is `use` instead of `loaders`/`loader`, like so:

```
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: cssLoader,
    exclude: /node_modules/
}
```

`postcss-loader` also suggests usage of `?importLoaders=1` when using the `css-loader` afterwards, so you should add that to your definition for `css-loader`:

```
PRODUCTION
    ?   ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
            loader: 'css-loader?minimize&localIdentName=' + cssIndentifier
        })
    :   ['style-loader','css-loader?importLoaders=1&localIdentName=' + cssIndentifier, 'postcss-loader']
```

And, finally, `options` should be passed directly to loaders. `LoaderOptionsPlugin.options.postcss` is not ideal (and I can't see that syntax supported anywhere in the documentation), and the options should be passed when defining the loader. Replace the string `'postcss-loader'` in `cssLoader` with an object for this behavior.

```
PRODUCTION
    ?   ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
            loader: 'css-loader?minimize&localIdentName=' + cssIndentifier
        })
    :   [
             'style-loader',
             'css-loader?importLoaders=1&localIdentName=' + cssIndentifier, 
             {
                 loader: 'postcss-loader',
                 options: {
                     plugins: function () { return [ autoprefixer ] }
                 }
             }
        ]
```

> The postcss loader readme specifies that `options.plugins` should be a function which returns an array, which is an odd way to work. If `return [ autoprefixer ]` doesn't work, the readme says to use `return [ require('autoprefixer') ]`, so try that.

I'm not sure which one of these would cause this issue exactly, but hopefully fixing these issues with your webpack config will fix your loader issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, that helped me:

1) add to your webpack.config.js this:

```
module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test:   /\.css$/,
                use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "postcss-loader"]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

2) then create a postcss.config.js with:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('autoprefixer')
  ]
}
```